# dialogs reshow when the app is resumed

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I have an app in which I can open many dialogs. This is one of them, they have the same code in the opening and in the onDismiss. 
This is the code for the onDismiss(), it's called when I do getDialog.dismiss():

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    ActividadPrincipal parent = (ActividadPrincipal) getActivity();
    parent.ActualizarActions();

}
```

The problem is: Let's suppose that I open a Dialog in my app, and then I close it (It executes the getDialog.dismiss()). When I click the Home button or change of app, and go back to my app, **every opened and closed (Or not closed) dialog appears again**. Any idea of what could be happening?

Edit:
This is the code of the class:

```
public class ActividadPrincipal extends Activity implements DialogActionsListener, DialogEventoListener, DialogAccionListener, DialogBrilloListener, DialogTextoAccionListener, DialogNroTextoAccionListener, DialogNroEventoListener, DialogTextoEventoListener, DialogNroTextoEventoListener, DialogModificarActionListener{

    ListView listView;
    static ArrayList<Action> listaActions;
    static ArrayList<EventoDefinido> listaEventosDefinidos;
    static ArrayList<AccionDefinida> listaAccionesDefinidas;
    static ArrayList<Action> listaActionsVacia = new ArrayList<Action>();
    static ArrayList<EventoDefinido> listaEventosDefinidosVacia = new ArrayList<EventoDefinido>();
    static ArrayList<AccionDefinida> listaAccionesDefinidasVacia = new ArrayList<AccionDefinida>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> listaActionsEliminadas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> listaAccionesDefinidasEliminadas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> listaEventosDefinidosEliminados = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static ArrayList<Integer> listaActionsEliminadasOrdenada = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> listaAccionesDefinidasEliminadasOrdenada = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> listaEventosDefinidosEliminadosOrdenada = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    static int contadorDePosiciones = 0;
    static int contadorDePosicionesAcciones = 0;
    static int contadorDePosicionesEventos = 0;

    ArrayList<Accion> listaAcciones;
    ArrayList<Evento> listaEventos;
    boolean Actions = true;
    boolean Eventos = false;
    boolean Acciones = false;
    boolean Ayuda = false;

    static int idAccionTemporal = 0;
    static int idEventoTemporal = 0;



    // Creo el adapter para Actions
    static AdapterActions adapterActions;

    //Creo el adapter para Eventos
    static AdapterEventosDefinidos adapterEventosDefinidos;

    // Creo el adapter para Acciones
    static AdapterAccionesDefinidas adapterAccionesDefinidas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad_principal);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listaActions = new ArrayList<Action>();
        listaEventosDefinidos = new ArrayList<EventoDefinido>();
        listaAccionesDefinidas = new ArrayList<AccionDefinida>();
        listaAcciones = new ArrayList<Accion>();
        listaEventos = new ArrayList<Evento>();

        //REGISTRO EL RECEIVER PARA HEADPHONES, QUE LO NECESITA
        broadcastAuriculares headsetReceiver = new broadcastAuriculares();
        this.registerReceiver(headsetReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG));
        final boolean isFirstTime = MyPreferences.isFirst(ActividadPrincipal.this);


        listView.setLongClickable(true);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);

      //ACÁ EMPIEZA LO DE ACTIONS
            if (isFirstTime){
            ActionsSQLite helper1  = new ActionsSQLite(this, "Actions", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper1.getWritableDatabase();


            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Actions (IdAccionDefinida, IdEventoDefinido, Activa) VALUES (2, 1, 1)");

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Actions (IdAccionDefinida, IdEventoDefinido, Activa) VALUES (6, 1, 0)");

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Actions (IdAccionDefinida, IdEventoDefinido, Activa) VALUES (5, 3, 1)");

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Actions (IdAccionDefinida, IdEventoDefinido, Activa) VALUES (3, 3, 0)");

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Actions (IdAccionDefinida, IdEventoDefinido, Activa) VALUES (1, 2, 1)");

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Actions (IdAccionDefinida, IdEventoDefinido, Activa) VALUES (4, 2, 0)");

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Actions (IdAccionDefinida, IdEventoDefinido, Activa) VALUES (9, 3, 0)");
            }

            ActionsSQLite base = new ActionsSQLite(this, "Actions", null,1);
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = base.getReadableDatabase();
            db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Actions",SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);
            Cursor c1 = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Actions", null);

            try{
                if(c1!=null){

                    int i = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id");
                    int j = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdAccionDefinida");
                    int k = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdEventoDefinido");
                    int l = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Activa");
                    boolean esActiva;

                    //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
                    while(c1.moveToNext()){
                        if (c1.getInt(l) == 0){
                            esActiva = false;
                        } else
                        {
                            esActiva = true;
                        }
                        //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                        Action Action = new Action(c1.getInt(i), c1.getInt(j), c1.getInt(k), esActiva);
                        listaActions.add(Action);
                    }
                }
                else 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                              "No hay nada :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
              catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("bdActions", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e); 
              }

              if(db1!=null){
                    db1.close();
            }   

              //ACA LO DE ACCIONESDEFINIDAS
              if (isFirstTime){
              AccionesDefinidasSQLite helper3  = new AccionesDefinidasSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "AccionesDefinidas", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase bd3 = helper3.getWritableDatabase();     


                bd3.execSQL("INSERT INTO AccionesDefinidas (IdAccion, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (1, 'Wi-Fi ON','')");

                bd3.execSQL("INSERT INTO AccionesDefinidas (IdAccion, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (2, 'Wi-Fi OFF','')");

                bd3.execSQL("INSERT INTO AccionesDefinidas (IdAccion, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (3, 'Modo Silencioso','')");

                bd3.execSQL("INSERT INTO AccionesDefinidas (IdAccion, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (4, 'Modo Vibrador','')");

                bd3.execSQL("INSERT INTO AccionesDefinidas (IdAccion, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (5, 'Modo Volumen','')");

                bd3.execSQL("INSERT INTO AccionesDefinidas (IdAccion, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (6, 'Notificación Vitaminas','Tomar vitaminas')");

                bd3.execSQL("INSERT INTO AccionesDefinidas (IdAccion, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (7, 'Brillo 20%','20')");

                bd3.execSQL("INSERT INTO AccionesDefinidas (IdAccion, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (8, 'SMS','1159064309+Presentar Proyecto')");

                bd3.execSQL("INSERT INTO AccionesDefinidas (IdAccion, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (9, 'Notif Ruidosa','Hacer ruido')");
                }

                AccionesDefinidasSQLite base3 = new AccionesDefinidasSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "AccionesDefinidas", null,1);
                SQLiteDatabase db3 = base3.getReadableDatabase();
                db3 = openOrCreateDatabase("AccionesDefinidas",SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);
                Cursor c3 = db3.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM AccionesDefinidas", null);
                try{
                    if(c3!=null){

                        int h = c3.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id");
                        int k = c3.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdAccion");
                        int i = c3.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Nombre");
                        int j = c3.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Aux");

                        //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
                        while(c3.moveToNext()){
                            //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                            AccionDefinida Accion = new AccionDefinida(c3.getInt(h), c3.getInt(k), c3.getString(i), c3.getString(j));
                            listaAccionesDefinidas.add(Accion);
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                              "No hay nada :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.i("bdAccionesDefinidas", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e); 
                }

                if(db3!=null){
                    db3.close();
                }


                //ACA LO DE EVENTOSDEFINIDOS
                EventosDefinidosSQLite helper2  = new EventosDefinidosSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "EventosDefinidos", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase bd2 = helper2.getWritableDatabase();

                if (isFirstTime){
                bd2.execSQL("INSERT INTO EventosDefinidos (IdEvento, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (1, 'Batería Baja','')");

                bd2.execSQL("INSERT INTO EventosDefinidos (IdEvento, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (2, 'Auriculares Conectados','')");

                //bd2.execSQL("INSERT INTO EventosDefinidos (IdEvento, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (3, 'Son las 22:30','22:30')");

                bd2.execSQL("INSERT INTO EventosDefinidos (IdEvento, Nombre, Aux) VALUES (4, 'Mensaje Específico Perdido','Buscar celular')");

                }

                EventosDefinidosSQLite base2 = new EventosDefinidosSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "EventosDefinidos", null,1);
                SQLiteDatabase db2 = base2.getReadableDatabase();
                db2 = openOrCreateDatabase("EventosDefinidos",SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);
                Cursor c2 = db2.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM EventosDefinidos", null);
                try{
                    if(c2!=null){

                        int h = c2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id");
                        int k = c2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdEvento");
                        int i = c2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Nombre");
                        int j = c2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Aux");

                        //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
                        while(c2.moveToNext()){
                            //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                            EventoDefinido Evento = new EventoDefinido(c2.getInt(h), c2.getInt(k), c2.getString(i), c2.getString(j));
                            listaEventosDefinidos.add(Evento);
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                              "No hay nada :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.i("bdEventosDefinidos", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e); 
                }

                if(db2!=null){
                    db2.close();
                }


                for (int i=0;i<listaActions.size()-1;i++)
                {
                    if(i == 0)
                    {
                        if (listaActions.get(i).getId() != 1)
                        {
                            for (int j=1;j<listaActions.get(i).getId();j++)
                            {
                                listaActionsEliminadas.add(j);
                            }
                        }
                    }else
                    if (listaActions.get(i).getId() != listaActions.get(i-1).getId() + 1)
                    {
                        for (int j=listaActions.get(i-1).getId();j<listaActions.get(i).getId();j++)
                        {
                            listaActionsEliminadas.add(j);
                        }
                    }
                }


                listaActionsEliminadas = listaActionsEliminadasOrdenada;


        // Ponemos el adapter por default para cargar en la actividad principal
        // Al adapter personalizado le pasamos el contexto y la lista que contiene
                // Añadimos el adapter al listview
                adapterActions = new AdapterActions(this, listaActions, listaActionsEliminadas);
                listView.setAdapter(adapterActions);










        //Declaración de Botones y programación
        Button btnActions = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnActions);
        Button btnAyuda = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAyuda);
        final Button btnCrear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_crear);


        btnActions.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //ACA EMPIEZA LO DE ACTIONS
                ActionsSQLite base = new ActionsSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "Actions", null,1);
                SQLiteDatabase db1 = base.getReadableDatabase();
                db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Actions",SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);
                Cursor c1 = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Actions", null);

                listaActions.clear();
                try{
                    if(c1!=null){

                        int i = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id");
                        int j = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdAccionDefinida");
                        int k = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdEventoDefinido");
                        int l = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Activa");
                        boolean esActiva;

                        //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
                        while(c1.moveToNext()){
                            if (c1.getInt(l) == 0){
                                esActiva = false;
                            } else
                            {
                                esActiva = true;
                            }
                            //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                            Action Action = new Action(c1.getInt(i), c1.getInt(j), c1.getInt(k), esActiva);
                            listaActions.add(Action);
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                  "No hay nada :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                  catch (Exception e){
                    Log.i("bdActions", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e); 
                  }

                  if(db1!=null){
                        db1.close();
                }   

                // Al adapter personalizado le pasamos el contexto y la lista que contiene
                // Añadimos el adapter al listview
                adapterActions = new AdapterActions(com.nahue.actions.ActividadPrincipal.this, listaActions, listaActionsEliminadas);
                listView.setAdapter(adapterActions);
                Actions = true;
                Eventos = false;
                Acciones = false;
                Ayuda = false;
                btnCrear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


        btnCrear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {




                if(Actions == true)
                {
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    Log.e("OnClick", "Creó el FragmentManager");
                    DialogActions Dialog = DialogActions.newInstance(listaAccionesDefinidas, listaEventosDefinidos);
                    Log.e("OnClick", "Creó el Dialog");
                    Dialog.show(fm, "dialog_actions");
                    Log.e("OnClick", "Mostró el dialog");
                } else if(Eventos == true)
                {
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    Log.e("OnClick", "Creó el FragmentManager");
                    DialogEvento Dialog = DialogEvento.newInstance(listaEventos);
                    Log.e("OnClick", "Creó el Dialog");
                    Dialog.show(fm, "dialog_eventos");
                    Log.e("OnClick", "Mostró el dialog");
                } else if(Acciones == true)
                {
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    Log.e("OnClick", "Creó el FragmentManager");
                    DialogAccion Dialog = DialogAccion.newInstance(listaAcciones);
                    Log.e("OnClick", "Creó el Dialog");
                    Dialog.show(fm, "dialog_acciones");
                    Log.e("OnClick", "Mostró el dialog");
                } else if(Ayuda == true)
                {
                    //HacerNada
                }
            }
        });

        final String[] ArrayAyuda = new String[] { "¿Qué es un evento?", 
                "¿Qué es una acción?",
                "¿Qué es una Action?",
                "¿Cómo se define una acción?",
                "¿Cómo se define un evento?",
                "¿Cómo se crea una Action?",
                "Acerca de Actions®"
               };

        btnAyuda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Al adapter personalizado le pasamos el contexto y la lista que contiene
                // Añadimos el adapter al listview
                Actions = false;
                Eventos = false;
                Acciones = false;
                Ayuda = true;
                btnCrear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapterAyuda = new ArrayAdapter<String>(com.nahue.actions.ActividadPrincipal.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, ArrayAyuda);

                listView.setAdapter(adapterAyuda);


            }
        });

                listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {                    
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (Actions == true)
                        {
                            Action ActionAModificar = listaActions.get(position);
                            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                            Log.e("OnClick", "Creó el FragmentManager");
                            DialogModificarAction Dialog = DialogModificarAction.newInstance(listaActions, listaAccionesDefinidas, listaEventosDefinidos, ActionAModificar);
                            Log.e("OnClick", "Creó el Dialog");
                            Dialog.show(fm, "dialog_modif_baja_actions");
                            Log.e("OnClick", "Mostró el dialog");

                        } else
                            if (Acciones == true)
                            {
                                if (listaAccionesDefinidas.get(position).getId() > 5)
                                {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActividadPrincipal.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("Deseas eliminar esta acción? Se eliminarán todas las Actions asociadas.")
                                       .setCancelable(false)
                                       .setPositiveButton("Sí", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {



                                               ActionsSQLite base1 = new ActionsSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "Actions", null,1);
                                                SQLiteDatabase db1 = base1.getReadableDatabase();
                                                db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Actions",SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);
                                                /*Cursor mCount= db1.rawQuery("SELECT Count(*) from Actions WHERE IdAccionDefinida = " + listaAccionesDefinidas.get(position).getId(), null);
                                                mCount.moveToFirst();
                                                int cantidad = mCount.getInt(0);
                                                mCount.close();*/

                                                db1 = base1.getWritableDatabase();
                                                db1.execSQL("DELETE FROM Actions WHERE IdAccionDefinida = " + listaAccionesDefinidas.get(position).getId());

                                                  if(db1!=null){
                                                        db1.close();
                                                }   




                                               AccionesDefinidasSQLite base = new AccionesDefinidasSQLite(ActividadPrincipal.this, "AccionesDefinidas", null,1);
                                                SQLiteDatabase db = base.getWritableDatabase();

                                                String miQuery = "DELETE FROM AccionesDefinidas WHERE Id = " + String.valueOf(listaAccionesDefinidas.get(position).getId());

                                                for (int i = 0;i<listaActions.size();i++)
                                                {
                                                    if (listaActions.get(i).getIdAccionDefinida() == listaAccionesDefinidas.get(position).getId())
                                                    {
                                                    removerActionEnLista(listaActions, listaActions.get(i), listaActionsEliminadas);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                removerAccionEnLista(listaAccionesDefinidas, listaAccionesDefinidas.get(position));


                                                db.execSQL(miQuery);
                                                ordenarArrayAccionesDefinidasEliminadas();
                                                ordenarArrayActionsEliminadas();
                                                contadorDePosicionesAcciones += 1;
                                                ActualizarActions();
                                                ActualizarAccionesDefinidas();
                                                //adapterAccionesDefinidas.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                                dialog.cancel();
                                           }
                                       })
                                       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                           }
                                       });
                                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                                    alert.show();
                                }

                            } else 
                                if (Eventos == true)
                            {
                                Log.e("El id del EventoDefinido es ", String.valueOf(listaEventosDefinidos.get(position).getId()));
                                if (listaEventosDefinidos.get(position).getId() > 2)
                                {

                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActividadPrincipal.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("Deseas eliminar este evento? Se eliminarán todas las Actions asociadas.")
                                       .setCancelable(false)
                                       .setPositiveButton("Sí", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {



                                               ActionsSQLite base1 = new ActionsSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "Actions", null,1);
                                                SQLiteDatabase db1 = base1.getReadableDatabase();
                                                db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Actions",SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);
                                                /*Cursor mCount= db1.rawQuery("SELECT Count(*) from Actions WHERE IdEventoDefinido = " + listaEventosDefinidos.get(position).getId(), null);
                                                mCount.moveToFirst();
                                                int cantidad = mCount.getInt(0);
                                                mCount.close();*/

                                                db1 = base1.getWritableDatabase();
                                                db1.execSQL("DELETE FROM Actions WHERE IdEventoDefinido = " + listaEventosDefinidos.get(position).getId());

                                                  if(db1!=null){
                                                        db1.close();
                                                }   




                                               EventosDefinidosSQLite base = new EventosDefinidosSQLite(ActividadPrincipal.this, "EventosDefinidos", null,1);
                                                SQLiteDatabase db = base.getWritableDatabase();

                                                String miQuery = "DELETE FROM EventosDefinidos WHERE Id = " + String.valueOf(listaEventosDefinidos.get(position).getId());

                                                for (int i = 0;i<listaActions.size();i++)
                                                {
                                                    if (listaActions.get(i).getIdEventoDefinido() == listaEventosDefinidos.get(position).getId())
                                                    {
                                                    removerActionEnLista(listaActions, listaActions.get(i), listaActionsEliminadas);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                removerEventoEnLista(listaEventosDefinidos, listaEventosDefinidos.get(position));


                                                db.execSQL(miQuery);
                                                ordenarArrayEventosDefinidosEliminados();
                                                ordenarArrayActionsEliminadas();
                                                contadorDePosicionesEventos += 1;
                                                ActualizarActions();
                                                ActualizarEventosDefinidos();
                                                //adapterAccionesDefinidas.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                                dialog.cancel();
                                           }
                                       })
                                       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                           }
                                       });
                                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            }
                        return false;
                    }


                 }); 






    }

    //Métodos de actualización para cuando se crea Action/Accion/Evento
    public void ActualizarActions(){
        Log.e("Actualizar Actions", "Entró");
        ActionsSQLite base = new ActionsSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "Actions", null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db1 = base.getReadableDatabase();
        db1 = openOrCreateDatabase("Actions",SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);
        Cursor c1 = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Actions", null);

        listaActions.clear();
        AdapterActions ActionsAdapterVacio = new AdapterActions(this, listaActionsVacia, listaActionsEliminadas);
        listView.setAdapter(ActionsAdapterVacio);
        try{
            if(c1!=null){

                int i = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id");
                int j = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdAccionDefinida");
                int k = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdEventoDefinido");
                int l = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Activa");
                boolean esActiva;

                //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
                while(c1.moveToNext()){
                    if (c1.getInt(l) == 0){
                        esActiva = false;
                    } else
                    {
                        esActiva = true;
                    }
                    //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                    Action Action = new Action(c1.getInt(i), c1.getInt(j), c1.getInt(k), esActiva);
                    listaActions.add(Action);
                }
            }
            else 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                          "No hay nada :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("bdActions", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos " + e); 
          }

          if(db1!=null){
                db1.close();
        }   

          adapterActions = new AdapterActions(this, listaActions, listaActionsEliminadas);
            listView.setAdapter(adapterActions);



    }


    public static void removerActionEnLista(ArrayList<Action> listaActions, Action ActionAEliminar, ArrayList<Integer> listaActionsEliminadas)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<listaActions.size();i++)
        {
            if (listaActions.get(i).getId() == ActionAEliminar.getId())
            {
                listaActions.remove(i);
                listaActionsEliminadas.add(ActionAEliminar.getId());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From which method you are opening the dialog? please post that class.

Comment: I have dialogs that are opened from buttons, and one (This one) that is opened from a longClick of a ListView. It does the same with both types of dialog, that's why I think that it's irrelevant code.

Comment: You say dialog closes when you close it and when you relaunch the app its appears again without any action. I feel problem is with that class only. You should put the class from where it is called otherwise I don't who can help you. Don't feel shy to put your code if you need help.

Comment: It has like a thousand of code lines, but if it helps you to help me, I'll post it

Comment: I've added the code. I deleted some irrelevant code 'cause it didn't let me to upload the question, it only admits 30000 characters.

Comment: I saw you code is quite messy. Dialog is shown when buttons are clicked/longClick. Can you log all the places that you call `dialog.show()` to see which section is called when close and open app?

Comment: No method is called, dialogs appear again with the same information they had before being closed, am I closing them properly?